# How can I use proxy with spread operator or object.assign?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind, es6-proxy

I need to have methods and store bound to 'this' in my callback function, but when I use the spread operator it doesn't work.
The reason for this as far as I know is that the spread operator returns a copy of the original. Therefore the proxy is never triggered.

What could I do in this case to make the proxy trigger?

```js
const setup = function (options, cb) {
  let store = new Proxy(options.store, {
    set(target, prop, value) {
      console.log(`changed ${prop} from ${target[prop]} to ${value}`);
      target[prop] = value;
      return true;
    },
  });
  cb.bind(store)(); // Works as expected
  // cb.bind({ ...store, ...methods })(); // Doesn't work
};

setup(
  {
    store: {
      n: 123,
    },
  },
  function () {
    this.n = 456;
  }
);
```

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the unbound `methods` variable, your example works as expected.

You won't see the message being printed. That's to be expected, since the expression `{...store}` essentially clones the (proxy) object `store`, with the effect that a new (regular) object is created and passed to `bind` and modified there.